# Django Error when calling to other project url to get data

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-requests

I have gone into a bit of trouble.

I have to call the url of Project 1 from Project 2 views to get the JSON data but when I am trying to call the url using requests it gives me "Max retries exceeded with url" error.
Both the projects are using Django 3 Project 1 is running on port 8001 and the other is on port 8000

Please help me out i thought it was a simple task as everything is working fine when doing the same in terminal or python file.

**EDIT**: Project 2 is running using docker-compose up while the other is running using manage.py  runserver command.

**# Project 1**
***views.py***

```
def send_master_data(request):
    return JsonResponse(provide_master_data())
```

***urls.py***

```
path('masterdata/', views.send_master_data, name='send_master_data'),
```

**# Project 2**

***views.py***

```
@decorators.login_required
def export_master_excel(request):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        res = session.get("http://127.0.0.1:8001/masterdata/")
    data = res.json()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{data["metadata"]["filename"]}"'

    wb = Workbook()
```

Comment: could you add ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']  into your project1 settings.py?

Comment: Accessing localhost doesn't require that. The problem is i am running Project 2 inside docker container using docker-compose up and Project 1 using runserver command.